# Dynamic Topic Subscription for Kafka Consumer in Spring Boot

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In my library class, I'm creating a Kafka consumer, and my configuration class is as follows:

```
@Service
public class ConsumerFactory {
    private TopicNameProvider topicNameProvider;

    private final static boolean ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT = false;
    private final static int MAX_POLL_RECORDS = 10;
    private final static int MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS = 600000;  // 10 min

    public ConsumerFactory(@Autowired(required = false) TopicNameProvider topicNameProvider) {
        this.topicNameProvider = topicNameProvider;
    }

    protected Properties fromKafkaProperties(KafkaConsumerProperties kafkaConsumerProperties){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkaConsumerProperties.getBootstrapServers());
        props.put("group.id", kafkaConsumerProperties.getGroupId());
        props.put("key.deserializer", ByteArrayDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put("value.deserializer", ByteArrayDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", String.valueOf(ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT));
        props.put("max.poll.records", String.valueOf(MAX_POLL_RECORDS));
        props.put("max.poll.interval.ms", String.valueOf(MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS));
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaConsumer consumer(KafkaConsumerProperties kafkaConsumerProperties) {
        KafkaConsumer kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer(fromKafkaProperties(kafkaConsumerProperties));
        kafkaConsumer.subscribe(topicNamesToSubscribe(kafkaConsumerProperties));
        return kafkaConsumer;
    }

    protected List<String> topicNamesToSubscribe(KafkaConsumerProperties kafkaConsumerProperties) {
        if (topicNameProvider != null) {
            return topicNameProvider.topicNames();
        } else if (kafkaConsumerProperties.getTopics() != null) {
            return Arrays.asList(kafkaConsumerProperties.getTopics());
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("No topic definition found to subscribe. Define topics either in application.yml " +
                    "in kafka.topics or implement a TopicsNameProvider bean.");
        }
    }
```

}

In my project, I create the topic name as follows:

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "messaging.mode", havingValue = "behaviour")
public class UserBehaviourTopicNameProvider implements TopicNameProvider {

    @Override
    public List<String> topicNames() {
        return List.of("user_behaviour_EMAIL_" + new Date().getHours());
    }
}
```

My goal is to change the topic name to which the consumer connects every hour. For example, at 9 AM, it should connect to a topic named user_behaviour_EMAIL_9, and at 10 AM, it should connect to user_behaviour_EMAIL_10, and so on. What would be the correct approach to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a list of one string here, and the topic name is only going to be evaluated once when the listener starts. Therfore, you'd need some logic at the end of every hour to stop and recreate your listener.

Otherwise, you could also consume with a regex pattern, and get data from the entire day at once.

Keep in mind that Kafka has a limit on number of topics, so maybe a topic with 24 partitions, for example, would be better pattern, where the producer can actually define a partition based on the timestamp